# Partial Sum Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

I am trying to solve the following:

Let  $\{a_n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be a decreasing sequence of positive terms. Check that:

$\frac{1}{2}(a_1+2a_2+4a_4+...+2^na_{2^n})\le s_{2^n}$ with  $s_{2^n}$ $=\sum_{k=0}^n a_{2^k}$

I was thinking of showing that:  $$2\times \sum_{k=0}^n a_{k}\ge\sum_{k=0}^n 2^ka_{k}\implies 2\times \sum_{k=0}^n a_{2^k}\ge\sum_{k=0}^n 2^ka_{2^k}$$is this valid?

Comment: This looks like some effort to prove Cauchy's Condensation  test for convergence of positive series...

Comment: ..and I don't think that's true in general. For example, for $\;n=3\;$ we'd get $$\frac12\left(a_1+2a_2+4a_4\right)=\frac12a_1+a_2+4a_4\le a_1+a_2+a_4\iff $$

$$\iff a_1+8a_4\le2a_1+2a_4\iff 6a_4\le a_1$$ Without further conditions I can't see why the above is true...

Comment: What seems to be true is $$\frac12\left(a_1+2a_2+\ldots+2^na_{2^n}\right)\le a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_{2^n}\;\ldots$$

Comment: I believe it is $2a_4$ not $4a_4$ @DonAntonio

Comment: If the comment did not LateX it is either because a bug in your computer or, most probably, a bug in the site. I see it LateXed...And it is $\;4a_4\;$ according to what **you** wrote...

Comment: your first expression, you made a multiplication a mistake @DonAntonio

Comment: Yes, that's true. Thanks. But it doesn't really matter: instead what is written there we'd get $\;2a_4\le a_1\;$, and still we need more info to deduce this is right.

Comment: @DonAntonio I asked for a one way implication, you are telling me the converse is not true, when I am asking if the "converse of the converse" is true

Comment: You claimed "Check that...", but "that" is false...or, at least, it must be proved. Why to bother with the continuation?

Comment: I did not claim that, it is an exercise I was trying to solve, and you showed me the exercise is wrong, but you have not validated or invalidated my ONE WAY implication, may you please do that, assuming the given ($\sum a_n$ is positive decreasing) is true. Forget about what "I have to check", please consider the validation of my one way implication. @DonAntonio

Comment: But Your left side is impossible if  **at least** one $\;a_n> 0\;$ ...! So since this can never happen but in the trivial and boring case $\;a_0=a_1=\ldots=0\;$, you can write whatever you want on the right side, yet it means nothing.

Comment: I see your point, now that I have edited it, does it make sense or not? @DonAntonio

Comment: Now it opens *a little more* the doors of logic, yet it still assumes rather harsh things about the descending sequence:$$2\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\ge\sum_{k=0}^n2^ka_k\iff a_0\ge\sum_{k=2}^n2^{k-1}a_k\;\ldots$$ Let me ask you: are you really trying to prove the Condensation Test for positive series? Or what are you trying to do here?

Comment: My professor gave us this exercise as motivation for the Cauchy condensation test yes. @DonAntonio I thank you for your time, this was helpful :)

Comment: @DonAntonio Is it okay if I delete this post, as the given was wrong, and messes up everything :P

Comment: You can delete it, I guess...yet people usually reads some comments below posts and will read what we wrote above. No harm done...